# Average time of day?

Tags: ruby, time, average

I'm writing a Rails app that will allow users to input what time of day they finish a task.

I am storing the times as `Time` objects, and I need a way to get the average time of day the task was completed for a user.

How can I accomplish this?

**My attempt with Малъ Скрылевъ's answer**

```
@deliveries = Delivery.all


times = Array.new
@deliveries.each do |d|
  times.push(d.time)
end
puts times # gives me [2000-01-01 06:15:00 UTC, 2000-01-01 07:18:00 UTC]
unless times.empty?
  @avg = Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) / times.size)
end
puts @avg #gives me 1999-12-31 23:46:30 -0700
```

Comment: you have an array of times?

Comment: @RSB essentially yes. I have a database of time objects. I can easily get one.

Comment: This question explains it well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223656/average-array-of-times-as-strings-in-ruby

Comment: @RSB I think that is different. Mine are actual ruby time objects

Comment: Look at my answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451064/293280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate avg by Time objects (they can be in different days). Something like this should work.

```
deliveries_at = @deliveries.map { |d| d.time.hour * 3600 + d.time.min * 60 + t.sec }
avg = deliveries_at.inject(:+) / deliveries_at.count
avg_hour = avg / 3600
avg_minute = (avg % 3600) / 60
avg_second = avg % 60
```

First line collect seconds-from-the-start-of-the-day for each delivery. Second line calculate average (in seconds) and last three lines turn it into hour/minute/second.

Answer (score 3):

Just you can use mathematic equations and statement on the `Time` object represented as `Integer`:

```
times = [ Time.now, Time.now ]
Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) / times.size)
```

#### Examples

And the same for the specific time array:

1. First:

   ```
   times = ["2000-01-01 08:13:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 18:14:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 16:55:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 23:53:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 00:56:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 02:57:00 UTC", "2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC"].map {|t| Time.parse(t) }
   Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) / times.size)
   # => 2000-01-01 13:09:51 +0300
   ```
2. Second:

   ```
   times = ['2000-01-01 06:15:00 UTC', '2000-01-01 07:18:00 UTC'].map {|t|Time.parse(t)}
   # => [2000-01-01 06:15:00 UTC, 2000-01-01 07:18:00 UTC] 
   Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) / times.size)
   # => 2000-01-01 09:46:30 +0300
   ```

Comment: `reduce(0, &:+)` can be simplified to `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: This seems to return the same time every time now that I've been testing it

Comment: @Deekor show up the input array you have

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ You have not understood my comment.

Comment: @sawa not quite understood =)

Comment: 2000-01-01 08:13:00 UTC
2000-01-01 18:14:00 UTC
2000-01-01 16:55:00 UTC
2000-01-01 23:53:00 UTC
2000-01-01 00:56:00 UTC
2000-01-01 02:57:00 UTC
2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC

Are the array values. No matter what I add or take away from that it comes out to 1969-12-31 17:33:20 -0700

Comment: @Deekor see update, the average time is quite properly calculated

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was leaving it an array of strings instead of an array of `Time` objects

Comment: Actually no - I put one time in of 2000-01-01 06:15:00 UTC and get the avg 1999-12-31 23:15:00 -0700

Comment: Ive updated my question with what i am doing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Deekor please specify the array dump directly in the question

Comment: Ok see the comment next to the `puts` statements

Comment: @Deekor I can't reproduce, please show exact dump

Comment: What do you mean exact dump?

Comment: Like this: `2000-01-01 08:13:00 UTC 2000-01-01 18:14:00 UTC 2000-01-01 16:55:00 UTC 2000-01-01 23:53:00 UTC 2000-01-01 00:56:00 UTC 2000-01-01 02:57:00 UTC 2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC`

Comment: that was the exact dump.. i only had 2 in my list that time

Comment: @Deekor so you can see the result for the dump in my answer

Comment: @Deekor please see update for second example, I got correct result.