# Ruby: How to sum array of Time objects?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a CardioExercise model with a duration attribute (Ruby 2.2.4 Time datatype).  I need to write a method to calculate the total duration of aerobic activity by a member during the past week.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
 def minutes_cardio_exercise_last_week
    array = @user.member.cardio_exercises.between_times(1.week.ago.beginning_of_week,            1.week.ago.end_of_week).map { |d| d[:duration] }
    hour, min, sec = ??
    (hour * 60 + min + sec / 60).round
 end
```

In the Rails console, the array contains:

```
=> [2000-01-01 00:25:00 UTC, 2000-01-01 00:30:00 UTC, 2000-01-01 00:53:20 UTC]
```

Those are the time objects I'm expecting, but I can't figure out how to sum the values to get something like 108 minutes of aerobic activity last week?

During my research, I found two posts that address the issue using PHP.  A third post is Ruby, but I can't figure out how to adapt the solution for my purpose.
    [How to Sum Time Value in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140165/how-to-sum-time-value-in-array)  |
    [How to sum time in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151876/how-to-sum-time-in-array)  |
    [Ruby: Average array of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280250/ruby-average-array-of-times)

I appreciate any help and insight.

Comment: Time is very much not the right class to use to represent durations. You will save yourself a lot of trouble (as you've already discovered) by just using an integer number of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.inject(0) { |sum, t| sum + ((t.hour * 60 + t.min + t.sec / 60).round) }
```

or even better if you have function to get minutes.

```
def minutes(t)
     (t.hour * 60 + t.min + t.sec / 60).round
end

def minutes_cardio_exercise_last_week
   array = @user.member.cardio_exercises.between_times(1.week.ago.beginning_of_week,            1.week.ago.end_of_week).map { |d| d[:duration] }
   array.inject(0) { |sum, t| sum + minutes(t) } 
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Manikandan.  That did the trick!  I had researched the inject method, but hadn't figured out how to use it. I'll read the docs on that method to get a better understanding.